# Readline for user input overwrites previous entry in R

Tags: r, user-input, readline

I'm trying to create a user input to create a list of stocks to be used to retrieve data from the internet.  I'm using `readline` to request the input, but each time I enter a symbol it overwrites the previous entry.  Is there a way to get the user to input and store the 5 symbols to be used in another package?  Below is what I'm using, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
##Input stock symbols to create a data series to optimize
Stk.List <- NULL
n <- 0:5
#for (i in seq (along=n)) {
for (i in seq(5)) {
  if (n[i] < 5) {
    Stk.List <- c(readline(prompt = "Input Stock Symbol: "))
  }
}
```

Comment: Your loop makes no sense... what's the point of `if (n[i] < 5)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use append.

```
 ##Input stock symbols to create a data series to optimize
 n <- 0:5
 Stk.List <- c()
 for (i in seq(5)) {
    if (n[i] < 5) {
    newstock <- readline(prompt = "Input Stock Symbol: ")
    Stk.List <- append(Stk.List, newstock)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `readLines()` to input a desired number of character strings, e.g.

```
cat('Input 5 stock symbols:\n')
readLines(n=5)
```

Otherwise, in your for loop use e.g. `Stk.List <- c(Stk.List, readline(prompt = "Input Stock Symbol: "))`

Comment: Thank you for your response, it is greatly appreciated!  I hadn't thought of that as you could probably tell>